# Issue installing puma gem with openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, openssl, puma

at my wit's end here...

I'm trying to install the puma gem for my Rails application to be hosted on Heroku. I found other issues and realized that I was getting errors because of OpenSSL. I fixed those, but now, when I try to run:

```
    gem install puma -- with-opt-dir=C:/openssl
```

I get the following error:

```
   checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... no
   checking for BIO_read() in -llibeay32... no
   *** extconf.rb failed***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, ...
```

and at the end...

```
   ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'with-opt-dir=C:/openssl' (>=0 ) in any repository
```

I've attempted multiple options, including re-installing ruby and rails, as well as any fixes to the OpenSSL issue. All other problems/solutions I've researched have not gotten me much closer to figuring out how to fix this problem. If it helps, I am using Ruby 2.0.0p643, Rails 4.20, and OpenSSL 1.0.0k. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This error is produced by changes in rubygems.org infrastructure

After installing ruby and manually installing Openssl, before you run

```
gem install puma -- with-opt-dir=C:/openssl
```

Follow these Steps to update your ruby CA
 
1. Download [AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem) and save it as  a .pem file
 
2. Locate RubyGems certificate directory in your installation (this will generally be in this place-> C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\lib\ruby\2.1.0\rubygems\ssl_certs )
 
3. Copy the new trust certificate downloaded in 1 to the ssl_cert in the above path
 
4. you can now run gem install puma -- with-opt-dir=C:/openssl

hope this helps :)

reference [here](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88)